# syntax error in simple LINQ statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am developing MVC app and I am using the LINQ in controller.

I am trying to get one rechord with below query, but its giving an error...

```
  Approval oAP = new Approval();
  oAP = db.Approvals.Where(e => (e.ApprovedBy.Id == loggedEmployee.Id) && (e.ReviewNo == oPaymentAdvice.ReviewCount));
```

Is there any wrong syntax ?

> Got the answer

```
oAP = db.Approvals.Where(e => (e.ApprovedBy.Id == loggedEmployee.Id) && (e.ReviewNo == oPaymentAdvice.ReviewCount)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: what is the error??will you please share with us?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PaymentAdviceEntity.Approval>' to 'PaymentAdviceEntity.Approval'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Side note: the part ` = new Approval()` is redundant.

Comment: oAP - Old aged pensioner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
e.ApprovedBy.Id = loggedEmployee.Id
```

For

```
e.ApprovedBy.Id == loggedEmployee.Id
```

You're comparing not assigning values.

Also you may add this

```
oAP = db.Approvals.Where(e => (e.ApprovedBy.Id == loggedEmployee.Id) && (e.ReviewNo == oPaymentAdvice.ReviewCount)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Because i'm assuming that you want to return only one

Comment: Did you add the FirstOrDefault?? and you're sure that you add the `==`

Comment: The error that you describes in the comment it's because you need to add the first or defaulkt

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

You should be able to drop the Where:

```
oAP = db.Approvals.FirstOrDefault(e => (e.ApprovedBy.Id == loggedEmployee.Id) && (e.ReviewNo == oPaymentAdvice.ReviewCount));
```

Personally, I try to avoid the First and FirstOrDefault functions, because if you know there is only one record and if you want to enforce this, you can use SingleOrDefault:

```
oAP = db.Approvals.SingleOrDefault(e => (e.ApprovedBy.Id == loggedEmployee.Id) && (e.ReviewNo == oPaymentAdvice.ReviewCount));
```

If you know there will always be (more than) one record, you can drop the 'OrDefault' part and use First() or Single().